# Maven/eclipse, How can eclipse honor maven runtime scope?

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, logback

In the pom.xml, i include logback & SLF4J like below, this works perfectly fine using maven build. It will give compilation error if i import directly from logback.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
          <dependencies>
                 <!-- We want to have slf4j with scope compile -->
                 <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                       <version>1.7.6</version>
                 </dependency>
          </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
          <!-- logback we only want runtime, compiletime we want SLF4J -->
          <dependency>
                 <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                 <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1.2</version>
                 <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

But how can I make eclipse honor the runtime scope of logback dependency and prevent import-suggestions from there?

Comment: Well for unit tests you could always add a `<scope>test</scope>`. As for the main method, I don't quite get your issue - could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: sorry I asked in the wrong way, will try to clarify now. Think its more of a maven/eclipse integration issue

Comment: I'am afraid this is not possible, eclipse has some trouble with implementing maven's runtime scope, see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414645)

Comment: Ah, that is to bad. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems not to be possible on Eclipse with a normal build, as mentioned by @A4L, it is a known bug, check [Bug 414645](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414645) and [Bug 376616](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376616). Eclipse (m2e) can't properly manage Maven dependencies scope.

However, if you place the runtime dependencies on a profile, then Eclipse will not add them to the classpath (the profile shouldn't be active by default, though). I just tested it on Eclipse Mars and it works perfectly.

Hence, in your case you could add to your POM:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>runtime</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
               <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
               <version>1.1.2</version>
               <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As such, it can't be used to compile on Eclipse. However, your build would then need to use it at runtime, running with `-Pruntime` in this case.

Although adapting your POM and build to an issue of an IDE might not be ideal, it could be a good compromise to achieve your goal.

Comment: I actually answered on a duplicate, which is probably not the best practice here, I should have instead flagged the newer question as duplicate and only answered here I guess, but since this question didn't have any upvote nor an answer, I couldn't flag the newer one as duplicate.

Comment: The bug has been fixed in version **4.9** (aka "2018-09") of Eclipse.

Comment: Adding the runtime scope allowed to compile and build the jar in Eclipse