# How to build an maven executable jar with external jar library?

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I am trying to build jar file of my app based on Maven. So I need to not include external jar library's to my build. I need that my app gives this external dependency in runtime from local maven repository or from local folder, those will contain these external libraries.
I configure my pom file for this dependency like this:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>compile</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                    <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
```

and trying to run this jar with this prefix `-Pcompile`. I am using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025345/eclipse-exclude-a-runtime-maven-dependency-from-the-build-path).

But in the runtime, when I am trying to execute a method, that using this external library, I've got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with the name of my class from my external library.

So how I can make a build that will use external jar libraries from local storage?

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758594/how-do-i-put-all-required-jar-files-in-a-library-folder-inside-the-final-jar-fil

Comment: It is much more common to build a self-contained executable jar file that includes all dependencies. Makes deployment so much easier and safer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven?rq=1

Comment: @Thilo: This does not work if you have a library like Bouncycastle in the dependencies as it is a signed crypto-provider and jar-with dependencies kills the jar-signatures which makes BC to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution to store jars outside the final maven build.
I was just need to add this jar to classpath with correct path. For this i add this to pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>${project.build.finalName}.lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>your.mainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.lib/some.lib-1.1.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>

                    </archive>
                </configuration>            
</plugin>
```